# TeXShop preview hangs in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: texshop, preview, macos

After upgrading to MacOS High Sierra, the preview window in TeXShop no longer updates the PDF output after typesetting.

I edit the LaTeX file in a separate (terminal) window using vim (after 30 years it's built into my fingers, so it's easier) and then use TeXShop to run (pdf)latex and display the result.  Until I upgraded from Sierra to High Sierra it always worked fine:  edit, click "typeset", and see the updated PDF in the preview window immediately.  Now it just freezes after typesetting:  the page previously visible doesn't update and no longer scrolls--it's just dead.  The only workaround I've found is to kill the preview window and reopen it.

I'm running TeXShop 3.97.  I get the same behavior for all LaTeX files (no no unusual packages, nothing fancy--even a single page with just text hangs up).  This worked fine for many years until the High Sierra update.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'll try tomorrow, if nobody comes along before.

Comment: Check to make sure you have the On Startup section of the Source Tab of TeXShop->Preferences set up for an External Editor. Also make sure the External Editor section of the Preview Tab of TeXshop->Preferences is set up for Automatic Preview Update.

Comment: Why use TeXShop to run LaTeX? That's something VIM could also do with ease (as well as opening a preview...)

Comment: Herb:  Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't fix it.  I already had both of these set as you suggest.

Comment: Skillmon:  I got started with TeXShop years ago when I got my first Mac--it seemed the easiest way to run it, and has always worked just fine (until now).

Comment: @ScottFulton : please get in touch with Dick Koch, the author of TeXShop,and report your problem. You might try logging out and back into you account or reboot as a last resort.

Comment: I tested on a High Sierra machine with TeXShop 3.97 and got no issue.

Comment: Rebooting doesn't fix it.  I'll try contacting Dick Koch as suggested.

Comment: Solution from Dick Koch:  in a terminal window, type "defaults write TeXShop FlashFix NO".  This fixes the problem for me (thanks, Dick).